# Как настроить разный текст кнопки и текст отправки в TelegramBot API

Tags: telegram-bot

Я хочу сделать кнопки под полем ввода и у меня получается.
Использую массив `ReplyKeyboardMarkup` и там создаю структуры `KeyboardButton`.

Проблема в том, что я хочу отображать текст кнопки один, а при нажатии чтоб отправлялся другой текст.

Как такого добиться?

Причина, я не хочу делать switch-case и проверять текст со смайликами.